# Rails -> swagger -> rswag: Is it possible to chain required properties with AND/OR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, swagger

In an rswag spec file, I have an enpoint with a POST method that is able to accept more than one combination of parameters as valid:

```
customer-id and contact-parameters (for a new contact)
OR
customer-id and contact-id (for an existing contact)
OR
customer-id and group-id (for a group of existing contacts)
```

Is it possible to represent (and test) this in one method-declaration in a spec file or should I declare the same method three times?